# Cannot append data from Firebase to Array SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

In my program, I'm reading data from Firebase. I'm trying to append this data in method to `Array` and then display it. Problem is during append this values, because I get an error: `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'arrayWithQuantity' is a 'let' constant`
I thought the problem is because I have declared a constant and not a variable, but when I changed that, the error still keeps showing up.

```
class getDataFromDatabase : ObservableObject {
      
    func readData(arrayWithQuantity: Array<Int>, arrayWithTime: Array<Double>){
       
        let db = Firestore.firestore() 
        db.collection("amounts").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
            
            if let e = err{
                print("There's any errors: \(e)")
            }
            
            if err != nil{
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
                   
            for i in querySnapshot!.documents{
                
                var quantityFromDb = i.get("amount") as! Int
                let timeFromDb = i.get("averageTimeRecognition") as! Double
                
                arrayWithQuantity.append(quantityFromDb)
              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where did I make a mistake? I am not sure is important in this case, but I'm using a SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
class getDataFromDatabase : ObservableObject { 
   var arrayWithQuantity = [Int]()
   var arrayWithTime = [Double]()
    func readData(){
     // here change them inside the callback
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Yes, it is what I looked for! Thank you so much, I couldn't find a solution, and it was that simple.